# Is there a command line calculator for byte calculations?

Tags: linux

Is there a command line calculator for linux where I can do the following;

```
 calc 560kB/12233kB
```

for example. Basic arithmetic desired and answers given as a decimal (in the case above) or with the appropriate SI prefix (kB, B, MB, GB, etc.).

Could `bc` do the trick somehow?

---

#### Solution

[GNU Units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/) does what I wanted to.

Comment: If not, that's an _awesome_ idea for a utility.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/gawk-awk-tcsh-how-to-convert-large-number-to-human-readable-mb-gb-etc-597921/

Comment: @Donal, link solves formatting problem, which is an opposite of arithmetical.

Comment: Try [GNU units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/)

Comment: Formally, this is a revered recomendation request, and should be closed. I won't vote for this though.

Comment: @chepner you may post your comment as answer. I see the OP did http://stackoverflow.com/a/25791429/ but then removed it.

Comment: I'm fine with the OP undeleting his post. I think adding an example to the answer would improve it. I only posted as a comment because I wasn't sure `units` actually allowed you to do calculations, and I couldn't be bothered to install it to test. (

Answer (score 6):

You can abuse `bc` for this if you remember that `number unit` actually is a shorthand for `number * unit`. One limitation of `bc` is that it only allows lower-case variables:

```
b=1
kb=1024
mb=1024*kb
...

scale=20
(560*kb)/(12233*kb)
.04577781410937627728
```

The next thing that I could think of is Python together with the [units package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units/).